# Onbeforeunload event in Android Chrome doesn't get fired

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, onbeforeunload, android-chrome

I need to save my session token in `localStorage` in order to get it back when user reloads the page:

```
window.addEventListener('beforeunload', this.savetoken.bind(this));
window.addEventListener('unload', this.savetoken.bind(this));

function async savetoken() {
    const token_ = await this.getToken();
    localStorage.setItem('sbk:token', token_);
    console.log('token saved in storage!!!', token_);
}
```

In desktop Chrome this work's perfectly, but in **mobile versione (Android Chrome 85) the unload/beforeunload event doesn't get fired** when closing browser or tab, it works only when refreshing the page.

Is there a way to get around this?

Answer (score 0):

As https://developer.chrome.com/blog/page-lifecycle-api/#the-unload-event says

> Many developers treat the `unload` event as a guaranteed callback and use it as an end-of-session signal to save state and send analytics data, but doing this is extremely unreliable, especially on mobile! The `unload` event does not fire in many typical unload situations, including closing a tab from the tab switcher on mobile or closing the browser app from the app switcher.

You can try `visibilitychange` and/or `pagehide` events to save data. And as a fallback you can save data periodically, e.g. once in a minute via `setInterval()`.

Comment: Trying to find a solution for this as well and visibilityChanged doesn't fire when the browser is closed on mobile. Will have a look at pagehide